# java script to parse an array from json

Tags: javascript, json

```js
{
    "took": 72,
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "2": {
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "Perf",
                "doc_count": 159874
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone guide me to take the value of buckets

Comment: You can try the following: `const buckets = json.aggregations['2'].buckets;`.  buckets will be an array of objects

Comment: var BucketList = yourdata;
console.log(bucketList.hits.total.value)

Comment: Hi Varun! This website is not meant for plainly getting your assignments done - you need to show some real effort behind trying to accomplish the goal and then post a question after making sure that a solution to your problem is not already available on this site. [Read the FAQs on the **/help** page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `JSON` should do the heavy lifting for you:

```js
const str = '{ "took": 72, "hits": { "total": { "value": 10000 } }, "aggregations": { "2": { "buckets": [{ "key": "Perf", "doc_count": 159874 }] } } }';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);
the_arry = obj['aggregations']['2']['buckets'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var myrs = { "took": 72, "hits": { "total": { "value": 10000 } }, "aggregations": { "2": { "buckets": [{ "key": "Perf", "doc_count": 159874 }] } } };
for(var i in myrs["aggregations"]) {console.log(myrs["aggregations"][i]['buckets']);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by parsing the JSON string with `var obj = JSON.parse()`. It gives you an object representation of the string to work on. Log the object to the console to easily discover the structure `console.log(obj);` or use an online JSON viewer to do that.
Assuming the structure is fixed, the `buckets` array can be accessed by `var buckets = obj.aggregations["2"].buckets`. Notice the access of the property `2`.